# Exchange server and a web server

Tags: web-server, exchange

I'm setting up an Exchange Server 2010 on Server 2008 R2.

I want to make my webserver (on a separated server) to use this server as the mail server.

I guess I'd have to change MX records to point to my exchange server, but what would be DNS settings on my exchange server considering I need outlook web app as well which will be running on the exchange server IIS .

and another question , can I add two MX records ? to two different mail servers ?
Does it then forward the receiving emails to both servers ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Are you saying that you have an app on your web server and you would like it to send mail through Exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your web server relay through your Exchange server.

- Your Exchange server has a name. Your Web server has a name. Those names should be different [A records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_record#A).
- Your [MX records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mx_record) are for mail delivery, so you'd configure those to point to your Exchange server's A record.
- Your [A records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_record#A) (address record) would point to your web server and mail server.
- MX records can be weighted and allow delivery to multiple destinations. However, I don't think you need this in your case. You have to get your main DNS issues situated first.

A sample zone file:

- **lime** is the A record for the Exchange server. The MX record for mail delivery points to "lime".
- The "A" record for the website points to a different server than "lime".
- The web server relays mail through **lime**.
- The OWA access can be accessed via **lime**.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what IM trying to do , thanks a lot, but a question where are these DNS records located on the webserver ? or the ns server which domain is pointed to !?

Comment: These DNS records reside on the authoritative nameserver for the domain. This can either be your registrar or another DNS hosting provider. Try looking your domain name up at http://www.whois.net if you're not sure.

Comment: Cool
so if my domain is pointing to my webserver ip, the dns records should be set on the web server , right ?

Comment: No. The DNS records are set with your DNS host.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess I'd have to change MX records to point to my exchange server, but what would be DNS settings on my exchange server considering I need outlook web app as well which will be running on the exchange server IIS .

I think what you're trying to ask is what A record should you use to get to OWA. The answer is to use whatever you want. `mail.example.com` is pretty common and easy to remember.

> and another question , can I add two MX records ? to two different mail servers ? Does it then forward the receiving emails to both servers ?

You can have more than one MX record. They have a value for priority. All mail will attempt to be delivered to the highest priority record and will only try lower priority servers if mail is undeliverable to the first choice.